# Can I set the default deployment for any project in Maven?

Tags: maven, deployment, teamcity, nexus

On our TeamCity build server every project now specifies the deployment repository either using the command line argument `-DaltDeploymentRepository` or `<distributionManagement>` in the project's POM file.

However we are planning to move to Nexus 3, and there would be considerable amount of work to make sure that all projects are configured correctly. There is also the fact that the deployment procedure has to be communicated with every developer.

Is it possible to specify the Maven deployment target in `settings.xml` or other so that unless otherwise specified any project that does a `deploy` on TeamCity will get deployed to the correct repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

...in `settings.xml`...no:

> #### [Servers](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Servers)
>
> The repositories for download and deployment are defined by the [`repositories`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repositories) and [`distributionManagement`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Distribution_Management) elements of the POM.

...or other...yes:

Create a (or, if already existing, use the) [parent POM](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Inheritance) from that all your projects inherit.

Comment: I didn't consider that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out another solution: TeamCity meta-runner. By producing a working build you can extract a meta-runner which is kind of like a build-step macro.

If you first get the deployment working you can extract a meta-runner using `Actions->Extract meta-runner...` in the TeamCity build configuration.

This shows an editor for the XML that specifies the build-runner. Remove all the non-deployment specific build steps, and you can provide build step parameters in the `meta-runner/settings/params` block. You will probably need to add pomLocation and the specify `%pomLocation%` in the build step's `<params>` block.